# How can I create multiple objects rapidly in a performance-effective manner?

Tags: java

I have a method similar to this:

```
public boolean myMethod(MyObject object)
{
    return new MethodHook(object).getReturnValue();
}
```

I am hooking this method, and am passing the MyObject value into the hook so I can use the data to determine what the "getReturnValue" is going to be. The problem is I have multiple threads (MANY threads) calling this method at once, and I can easily see a performance problem with new MethodHook objects being created at every thread call.

How can I do this exact operation (yes, I need the MethodHook objects) to be BOTH performance efficient, and thread safe? (I tried a singleton, but it didn't work out as I realized that you can't store multiple "MyObject"s used by different threads in a single object -- the singleton)

Comment: You can use `ThreadLocal` to have one `MethodHook` object per thread

Comment: You can try to implement the [Flyweight design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-flyweight)

Comment: Can't you make the method `getReturnValue()` static and pass the `object` as a paramether? Why do you have to create a new object every time?

Comment: @Amongalen I can't make it static, because each thread is giving a different "object" value that needs to be handled by the MethodHook. I am creating new MethodHooks so that I can handle all threads' MyObjects.

Comment: @Oleg I tried using ThreadLocal. While the behaviour of the program remained consistent, the performance dropped significantly lower.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a "MethodHookPool" like:

```
public class MethodHookPool {
   private Stack<MethodHook> freeHooks;

   public boolean withFreeHook(MyObject object) {
      MethodHook hook;
      synchronized(freeHooks) {
         hook = freeHooks.isEmpty() ? new MethodHook() : freeHooks.pop(); 
      }

      try {
         hook.setMyObject(object);
         return hook.getReturnValue();
      }
      finally {
         synchronized(freeHooks) {
            freeHooks.push(hook);
         }
      }
   }
}

MethodHookPool pool;

public boolean myMethod(MyObject object) {
   return pool.withFreeHook(object);
}
```

But I am not sure if this will increase performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this, but unfortunately the performance was not improved.

Comment: I think without an insight into MethodHook it would be hard to figure out the bottle neck.

Comment: The MethodHook is basically just a storage object to manipulate the return value of "myMethod," and it stores the "object" parameter so that handlers can use that data to determine what return value to output. I am basically running an event bus, and need to call the event (the MethodHook) in a performance-efficient manner.